# Resharper find code issues only in tfs current pending changes set files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, resharper

Is there any way to find code issues via reshaper **only in current pending changes set files**, not in entire solution, current project. Is there any workaround to achive the same.

[image: resharper find code issues in solution/current project]

I'm unable to find any way to do that in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Since ReSharper doesn't have integration with the Visual Studio Version Control System, there is no way for ReSharper to see these pending changes.